# I am still getting the error ImportError: No module named requests after installing requests using pip3

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

I am using Python 3.6.5 in Visual Studio Code on a Mac.
I installed pip3 and it is up to date, when I put in the command :

```
$ pip --version
```

I get this result :

```
 pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

I imported the module requests.
And when I put in this command :

```
pip freeze | grep requests
```

I get this result :

```
requests==2.19.1
```

So I thought this meant the requests module was installed, but I still get the error **ImportError: No module named requests** when I put in : import requests in my file and try to run it.

Can somebody explain what is happening? Thank you :)

Comment: How are you trying to run the file?  Are you sure you're using the same version of Python as pip is using?

Comment: If, in the same place `import requests` fails you instead wrote `import sys; print(sys.path)`, is the path you list (`/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`) there?

Comment: Also: you've gone back and forth between referring to `request` and `requests` in this question, and you clearly typed out the error instead of copying and pasting it, and didn't show us your code, so… are you sure you didn't `import request`?

Comment: Anyway, the most likely problem is that you're using Apple's pre-installed Python 2.7, not your Python 3.6, because you're just typing `python`, or using `#!/usr/bin/env python` in your script, or similar. (Even if the 2.7 `python` comes before the 3.6 `python` in your PATH, `pip` will still pick up the 3.6 version, because Apple's 2.7 doesn't include `pip`.) If so, the solution is to use `python3` instead of `python`.

Comment: I changed the python path in my script to python3 to make sure the 3.6 version is being used, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I checked and I was writing import requests.. so sadly not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, turns out I was using an extension called Code Runner and I thought it used the integrated terminal, where I had configured Python3. But turns out it uses its own interpreter. I added the following to my user settings:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python": "python3",
}
```

and now it works! :)